# My dad is a UK citizen, does he need a separate ESTA for each trip?

Tags: usa, esta, uk-citizens

my dad is uk citizen living in Thailand for 15 years received a ESTA to travel to US for 90 days, he is going back to Thailand for 30 days and will be traveling back to US for another 90 days does he need another ESTA

Answer (score 6):

Probably not.  ESTA is valid for two years, or until the expiration date of the passport, whichever comes sooner.

> Approved ESTA applications are valid for a period of two years, or until the passport expires, whichever comes first, and multiple trips to the United States without the traveler having to re-apply for another ESTA. When traveling to the U.S. with the approved ESTA, you may only stay for up to 90 days at a time - and there should be a reasonable amount of time between visits so that the CBP Officer does not think you are trying to live here. There is no set requirement for how long you must wait between visits.
>
> Travelers whose ESTA applications are approved, but whose passports will expire in less than two years, will receive an ESTA valid until the passport's expiration date.
>
> A new ESTA authorization is required if:
>
> - You are issued a new passport
> - You change your name (first and/or last)
> - You change your gender (ESTA does not currently have a gender X to choose from on the application. It is suggested that the traveler choose whichever choice they feel most comfortable with. ESTA will not be denied solely on the gender chosen on the application. )
> - Your country of citizenship changes
> - Your circumstances change, e.g., you are convicted of a crime of moral turpitude or you develop a contagious disease. Such a change may require you to get a visa to travel to the U.S. You must re-apply and your application must reflect the change in your circumstances or you may be denied entry upon arrival in the United States.
>
> DHS recommends that you apply for ESTA authorization as soon as you know you will be traveling to the United States under the VWP.

Source: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1072